# Filter NaN values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, nan

```
y = data.loc[data['column1'] != float('NaN'),'column1']
```

The code above is still returning rows with NaN values in 'column1'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN`, by definition is not equal to `NaN`.

```
In [1262]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[1262]: False
```

Read up about the [mathematical concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) on Wikipedia.

---

**Option 1**

Using *`pd.Series.notnull`*:

```
df

   column1
0      1.0
1      2.0
2    345.0
3      NaN
4      4.0
5     10.0
6      NaN
7    100.0
8      NaN

y = df.loc[df.column1.notnull(), 'column1']
y

0      1.0
1      2.0
2    345.0
4      4.0
5     10.0
7    100.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**

As MSeifert [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146235/validation-if-value-not-equals-nan-still-returning-nan-values#comment79254326_46146262), you could use *`np.isnan`*:

```
y = df.loc[~np.isnan(df.column1), 'column1']
y

0      1.0
1      2.0
2    345.0
4      4.0
5     10.0
7    100.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**

If it's just the one column, call *`pd.Series.dropna`*:

```
y = df.column1.dropna()
y

0      1.0
1      2.0
2    345.0
4      4.0
5     10.0
7    100.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: or `np.isnan` :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me so quickly @COLDSPEED! You rock!